# Why is clearTimeout not working in this case?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why the clearTimeout function isn't working below? Whenever I call it, the setTimeout function is still called... Thanks!

```
let todo = document.getElementById('todo');
let todoList = document.getElementById('todo_list');
let timer;

form.addEventListener('submit', newtodo);

function newtodo() {
    let todoItem = document.createElement('li');
    let timesItem = document.createElement('i');

    timesItem.classList.add('fa', 'fa-times-circle');

    todoItem.innerHTML = todo.value;

    todoList.appendChild(todoItem).prepend(timesItem);

    timesItem.addEventListener('click', function() {
        todoItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        todoItem.style.color = "grey";

        timer = setTimeout(removeTodoItem, 3000);;    
        
        timesItem.addEventListener('click', function() {
            todoItem.style.textDecoration = "none";
            todoItem.style.color = "black";
            clearTimeout(timer);            
        });
    });   

    todo.value = '';

    function removeTodoItem() {
        todoList.removeChild(todoItem);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Adding a new event listener inside another event handler is a really bad practice and probably not doing what you expect. The new event listener does not replace the existing one...it simply adds another listener and will keep adding every time you click

Comment: got it. can you point me in the right direction how to solve this?

Comment: I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with for anyone who's interested:

```
let todo = document.getElementById('todo');
let todoList = document.getElementById('todo_list');
let timer;

form.addEventListener('submit', newtodo);

function newtodo() {
    let todoItem = document.createElement('li');
    let timesItem = document.createElement('i');

    timesItem.classList.add('fa', 'fa-times-circle');

    todoItem.innerHTML = todo.value;

    todoList.appendChild(todoItem).prepend(timesItem);

    let idx = 0;

    timesItem.addEventListener('click', function() {

        if(idx == 0) {
            todoItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
            todoItem.style.color = "grey";
            timer = setTimeout(removeTodoItem, 3000);;  
            idx++;  
        } else {
            todoItem.style.textDecoration = "none";
            todoItem.style.color = "black";
            clearTimeout(timer);
            idx--;
        }         
    });

    todo.value = '';

    function removeTodoItem() {
        todoList.removeChild(todoItem);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's Whats happening in this scenario:

**newTodo** function will run after the form has been submitted.

and by running **newTodo** you define onClick event listener for a button and a timeout function that will trigger under 3 seconds.

if You click **timesItem** before 3 seconds it will clearTimeout and Wont run.

If you have any other question ask me.